# Login failed for user 'sa'. ...... [CLIENT: 59.48.47.215]

Tags: sql-server-2008, authentication, attacks, windows-event-log

I have an Amazon EC2 instance and i don't have anything running on it yet but my event log is full of below error

*"Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: An attempt to login using SQL authentication failed. Server is configured for Windows authentication only. [CLIENT: 59.48.47.215]"*

What is this ? is someone trying to attack or is it something internal ?
I know about the authentication mix mode and etc...
just want to make sure what it is before I change the sql security settings.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're expecting traffic from China Telecom, then yes, it's an attempt at an attack - though obviously an ineffective one in this case, since the `sa` account isn't enabled in windows-only mode.

I'd recommend against having port 1433 accessible to the outside world.

Comment: I thought it was blocked by default on windows firewall! How do i block it ?